# Samsung Music Player - Multiple Genres

Tags: samsung, music-player

I have a library of around 6000 songs. Each one of them is tagged properly, however, there are songs, which have multiple genres and some do have multiple artists.

I tried separating them with delimiter ";" it didn't work, the music player showed the genre in the list as Pop;Rock;Dance instead of showing three different genres.

I also tried other ways of formatting like, "//" or "/" or "\" but none of them worked!

Is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: What phone in particular are you using, and what type of file are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a software name `Virtual DJ`. It can hep you to change your song Genres and many things which could help you to properly manage the `Genre Section` in `Samsung Music Application`